# qbxml QuickBooks XML BillAddress invalid according to DTD

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

Version 13.0 of qbxml.  Why is the validator listing XML elements that are not in my XML and are not required as something it's expecting?

In all the references I've seen it lists Memo after BillAddress for InvoiceAdd.

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

```
Line: 20
LinePos: 22
Src Text: <BillAddress>
Reason: Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.
Expecting: ItemSalesTaxRef, Memo, CustomerMsgRef, IsToBePrinted, IsToBeEmailed, IsTaxIncluded, CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef, Other, Exchange....

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="43">
      <InvoiceAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
          <FullName>GORILLA SPRAY FOAM LLC</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <ARAccountRef>
          <FullName>Accounts Receivable</FullName>
        </ARAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-12-01</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>9690</RefNumber>
        <PONumber>JN 102317</PONumber>
        <ShipDate>2017-10-23</ShipDate>
        <ShipMethodRef>
          <FullName>x</FullName>
        </ShipMethodRef>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>GORILLA SPRAY FOAM LLC</Addr1>
          <Addr2>2332 HIGHWAY 65</Addr2>
          <City>MORA</City>
          <State>MN</State>
          <PostalCode>55051</PostalCode>
        </BillAddress>
        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>S 8000</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>x</Desc>
          <Quantity>2</Quantity>
          <Amount>x</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>
        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>S 8020</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>x</Desc>
          <Quantity>2</Quantity>
          <Amount>x</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>
        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>Delivery Charge</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>Delivery Charge</Desc>
          <Amount>75.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>
        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>Sales Tax</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>Minnesota Sales Tax</Desc>
          <Amount>2.58</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>
      </InvoiceAdd>
    </InvoiceAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the tags in qbXML is important.

If the OSR shows, for example, that the `ShipMethod`, `ShipDate`, and `PONumber` tags come AFTER the `BillAddress` tag, then you MUST follow that order.

Refer to the OSR:

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Make sure your tags are in the correct order. Currently they are not due to the `ShipDate`, `ShipMethodRef`, and `PONumber` tags being prior to `BillAddress`.

Comment: Thanks Keith, not sure how I missed that.  Your library and site has been invaluable getting the web connector working.

Comment: Thank you Keith, you saved me! I spent several hours trying to understand what is wrong with my <Phone> tag.